# Prove or disprove: $99^{100}+100^{101}+101^{99}+1$ is a prime number

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Prove or disprove: $$99^{100}+100^{101}+101^{99}+1$$ is a prime number.

My idea: let $100^{101}=x^{x+1}$,then
$$99^{100}+100^{101}+101^{99}+1=(x-1)^{x}+x^{x+1}+(x+1)^{x-1}+1$$ is prime number？

I have solved following problem before:

> Show that $$5^{100}+5^{75}+5^{50}+5^{25}+1$$ is not prime number.

Let $x=5^{25}$, then
$$x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=(x^2+3x+1)^2-5x(x+1)^2$$

Note that
$$5x(x+1)^2=5^{26}(x+1)^2=[5^{13}(x+1)]^2$$

But for my problem it looks I can't use this approach.

Comment: It had better not be a prime number, because otherwise that would make this a very very difficult problem to prove...

Comment: Note that $$(x -1)^{x-1} = (100^{101} - 1)^{100^{101}-1}$$ similarly $(x+1)^{x-2} = 101^{99}$ is wrong

Comment: Wolfram says it isn't although you will need a pro account to check the prime decomposition. Also this is an approximately 200 digit number. Too large for a normal computer to factorise but I would say that some sufficiently elaborated algorithms with a powerful enough computer should be able to factor it. 3 years ago a classmate factored an 180 digits number in an RSA encryption exercise.

Comment: Here's an exercise for you: write up a quick script to compute this number modulo an input prime. ;-)

Comment: Divisible by 825277.

Comment: I guess it is divisible by $11$?

Comment: @Chen Wang how did you compute that?

Comment: @dani_s I think it's 8 mod 11.

Comment: @dani_s [Alpertron's applet](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM).

Comment: @china math where did you get this problem from?

Comment: OP should state that this is a "no calculators allowed" problem, if it even is one.

Comment: @YiyuanLee well of course, no one here is going to rest till we get a good answer. helps to know, *what* we have to prove. I am thinking along the lines of factor theorem maybe.

Comment: @dani_s,this problem is my frend ask me,maybe is Maths Olympic question

Comment: @chinamath okay. makes sense for it to be in an olympiad.

Comment: @chinamath could you edit the post to say something like "we have found a factor 825277. so it is not prime, but i am looking for proof without calculator"?

Comment: I've looked at $$k\mapsto k^{k+1}+(k+1)^{k+2}+(k+2)^k+1$$ with the aim of proving the claim by induction. Didn't work, but here some thoughts: The map preserves the property of being even/odd. The result is prime for $k=1$ and $k=3$, but isn't prime for the next 1000 $k$'s I've checked computationally. I couldn't see any pattern in the prime factors though, they are big and jump in value. Code in Mathematica is 'FactorInteger /@ 
 Table[k^{k + 1} + (k + 1)^{k + 2} + (k + 2)^k + 1, {k, 1, 33}]'

Comment: @NikolajK. nice property about being preserving even-odd. was obvious, yet didn't notice.

Comment: our number is $k=99$? yes?

Comment: @NikolajK. don't have mathematica. can you post a link to a text file or something?

Comment: @Sabyasachi: A text file of what?

Comment: @NikolajK. list of prime factors. of the 1000k's you have checked. but on second thought. nevermind. not much use i figure.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple Python script to calculate $a^b$ mod $p$:

```
def powmod(a, b, p):
  if b==0: return 1
  tmp = powmod(a, b/2, p)**2
  if b%2!=0: tmp *= a
  return tmp%p
```

To check divisibility of your function by $p$, you can use:

```
def ck(p):
  val = powmod(99,100,p) + powmod(100,101,p) + powmod(101,99,p) + 1
  return (val%p == 0)
```

Finally, testing all the numbers through $10^6$ for divisibility:

```
>>> filter(ck, xrange(2,1000000))
[825277]
```

So it's not prime.

Comment: +1. python has inbuilt $a^b \mod c $ though. call `pow(a,b,c)`

Comment: Oh, um, I knew that already, I just thought it'd be educational.  (j/k -- thanks for the tip.)

Comment: oh okay then. +1 to your comment, for education :p

Comment: Not surprisingly, Python's built-in implementation is substantially faster.

Comment: To improve the performance you should use a sieve so you only check for divisibility by *prime numbers*

Comment: Unless you already have a large database of primes, building a sieve would probably take longer than just doing something simple like "checking the odds".

Answer (score 3):

Similar Mathematica code is `FactorInteger[99^100 + 100^101 + 101^99 + 1, 2]` which returns $825277$ and $\frac{99^{100} + 100^{101} + 101^{99} + 1}{825277}$.

Comment: never knew about the second argument for Factor. Thanks.+1

Answer (score 1):

To promote [Sage](http://sagemath.org/):

```
sage: a = 99^100 + 100^101 + 101^99 + 1
sage: N = 10^100
sage: for p in primes(N):
....:     if a % p == 0:
....:         print p
....:         break
....:         
825277
```