# find all integer solutions of $y^2=x^3-2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, mordell-curves

I’m blind about integer solutions of a polynomial. I have no number theory background, but I’m curious about how to figure out all integer solutions of a polynomial, for example this question. It is said there are only two solutions, but I can’t give a proof. What I can show is that there are no even solutions. I am actually curious about the general pattern to consider this kind of problem. Can anyone give me some ideas or references? Thanks!

Comment: I  am quite sure this has been asked and answered before. The solution uses a little algebraic number theory. I have a solution on file, and if no one finds the duplicate, I can write out a solution tomorrow.

Comment: This equation is a special case of the Mordell equation, $y^2 =x^3 +A$. A tremendous amount of work has been done on the Mordell equation, and solutions have been tabulated for large ranges of values of $A $, for example, [here](http://tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp/simath/MORDELL/MORDELL+).

Comment: To add a bit, the obvious solutions $x=\pm 5$, $y=3$ are the only ones, and the proof I am thinking of uses the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ has unique factorization.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Sorry, but how do you get the solutions $(5, 3)$ and $(-5, 3)$? They do not solve the equation $y^{2} = x^{3} - 2$. Should not it be $(3, 5)$? And $(-3, 5)$ does not work because $(-3)^{3} - 2 = -29 \neq 5^{2}$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have written $y=\pm 5$, $x=3$.

Comment: We may first narrow down the solution scope by noting that $x$ can only be integers $\geq 2,$ because if $x  \leq 1$ then no real number $y$ can be such that $y^{2} < 0$ and because the function $x \mapsto -\sqrt{x^{2} - 2}$ is meaningful iff $x \geq 2.$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solutions to $y^2 = x^3 + k$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107144/solutions-to-y2-x3-k), and [Diophantine equation: $x^2=y^3-2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677422/diophantine-equation-x22-y3)

Comment: @DietrichBurde better link this to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473180) because the one you mentioned asks for a specific proof technique.

Comment: @barto: I agree. Do you know how I can change this ? I cannot retract my vote because then I am not allowed to vote again for a duplicate.

Comment: I think it's not possible. I found this related discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193654