# Is $n=26$ the only integer satisfying $n-1$ being a square and $n+1$ being a cube?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

I guess it is possible to solve it by ring theory, but I would prefer an elementary method instead. I can only figure out that $n$ is an even integer, otherwise there will be contradiction w.r.t. modulo $4$. I have also tried to modulo several other integers(3, 5, 8, 9, 10) but haven't got any contradiction yet. Any discussion is welcomed!

Comment: By ring theory do you mean a method similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473180/the-diophantine-equation-x2-2-y3 and Theorem 3.4 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473180/the-diophantine-equation-x2-2-y3) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473180/the-diophantine-equation-x2-2-y3), or even [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677422/solve-x22-y3-using-infinite-descent) for a discussion about the possibility of a more elementary proof.

Comment: A modulo approach cannot show that there is only one solution. A warning concerning the so-called "elementary proofs" : "elementary" does not mean "easy". A stronger version of your question is which pairs of two perfect powers have difference $2$, this is related to Pillai's conjecture.

Comment: You can conclude that $3\not \mid n$ because $3\mid n \Rightarrow n-1 \equiv -1 \bmod 3$ which is a contradiction because  squares cannot be $\equiv -1 \bmod 3$. Hence, $3$ divides one of $(n-1),(n+1)$. So either $(3x)^2+2=y^3$ or $x^2+2=(3y)^3$

Comment: Further to my previous comment: If $(3x)^2+2=y^3$, then $y^3\equiv 2 \bmod 9$. But cubes $\bmod 9$ are limited to $\{-1,0,1\}$, so solutions of this form are impossible. If $x^2+2=(3y)^3$, then $x^2\equiv -2 \bmod 27 \Rightarrow x\equiv \pm 5 \bmod 27$. So solutions to the original question are limited to ${(n-1)} \equiv 25 \bmod 27$, and $27\mid (n+1)$

Comment: This is discussed in Dickson's "History of the Theory of Numbers" volume 2, chapter XX. In particular, it says there that "Fermat stated that he could give a rigorous proof that 25 is the only integral square which is less than a cube by 2."

Answer (score 4):

**Lemma.**
Let $a$ and $b$ be coprime integers, and let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers such that $a^2+2b^2=mn$. Then there are coprime integers $r$ and $s$ such that $m=r^2+2s^2$ divides $br-as$. Furthermore, for any such choice of $r$ and $s$, there are coprime integers $t$ and $u$ such that $a=rt-2su$, $b=ru+st$, and $n=t^2+2u^2$ divides $bt-au$.

*Proof.*
Assume the theorem is false, and let $m$ be a minimal counterexample. Evidently $m > 1$ since the theorem is trivially true for $m=1$.

Note that $b$ is coprime to $m$. Let $A$ be an integer such that $Ab \equiv a\!\pmod{m}$, chosen so that $\tfrac{-m}{2} < A \le \tfrac{m}{2}$. Then $A^2+2 = lm$ for some positive integer $l < m$. Clearly $l$ cannot be a smaller counterexample than $m$, and so there exist coprime integers $r$ and $s$ such that $m=r^2+2s^2$ divides $br-as$.

Let $t = \tfrac{ar+2bs}{m}$ and $u=\tfrac{br-as}{m}$. Direct calculation confirms the equations for $a$, $b$, and $n$. From $n=t^2+2u^2$, we deduce that $t$ is an integer because $u$ is an integer, and $t$ and $u$ are coprime because $\gcd(t,u)$ divides both $a$ and $b$. Finally, note that $n$ divides $bt-au=sn$.

Hence $m$ is not a counterexample, contradicting the original assumption. $\blacksquare$

**Corollary.**
Let $a$ and $b$ be coprime integers with $m$ an integer such that $m^3=a^2+2b^2$. Then there are coprime integers $r$ and $s$ such that $a=r(r^2-6s^2)$ and $b=s(3r^2-2s^2)$.

*Proof.*
Evidently $m$ is odd since $a^2+2b^2$ is at most singly even. And $a$ and $m$ must be coprime. Using the theorem, we have $m=r^2+2s^2$ and $m^2=t^2+2u^2$. Then $m$ divides $a(ur-ts)=t(br-as)-r(bt-au)$, and therefore $m \mid (ur-ts)$. The lemma can then be reapplied with $a$ and $b$ replaced by $t$ and $u$. Repeating the process, we eventually obtain integers $p$ and $q$ such that $p^2+2q^2=1$. The only solution is $q=0$ and $p=\pm1$. Ascending the path back to $a$ and $b$ (reversing signs along the way, if necessary) yields $a=r(r^2-6s^2)$ and $b=s(3r^2-2s^2)$, as claimed. $\blacksquare$

**Theorem.**
The Diophantine equation $X^3 = Y^2+2$ has only one integer solution, namely $(x,y) = (3, \pm 5)$.

*Proof.*
Evidently $y$ and $2$ are coprime. By the corollary, we must have $b=1=s(3r^2-2s^2)$ for integers $r$ and $s$. The only solutions are $(r,s)=(\pm 1,1)$. Hence $a=y=r(r^2-6s^2)=\pm 5$, so $(x,y)=(3,\pm 5)$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: @lhf: Replaced link with duplicate of proof.

Comment: Adapted from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473180/the-diophantine-equation-x2-2-y3/4190841#4190841