How to solve $y^2=x^3+3$ where x,y integer?
In my Number theory class my exam problem was to solve Mordell equation $y^2=x^3+3$.
But I don't know how to solve this. One approach was to subtract 3 and use the fact that $F=Q(\sqrt 3)$ is ED, but what I can do was just transforming this equations to another Thue equations... So I want to know how to solve this.

y= 2,-2
x = 1 ez

@uggupuggu Did you actually read the question?

@uggupuggu Proving there are no other solutions is less "ez", though. There is a similar question ( https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473180/the-diophantine-equation-x2-2-y3 ) but its approach can't be used directly since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ is not UFD.

$\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ is a UFD.

Cf. this question

May  you use the writing
$$ y^2-4 =x^3-1$$
$$ (y-2)(y+2) =(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$$

@SomeCallMeTim Indeed it is. I am sorry for the misleading comment.

I think the reason why the method for $y^2=x^3-2$ couldn't be applied is that Z[sqrt(3)] is a real quadratic field, so it has infinitely many units. So we need to solve $y+\sqrt 3 =u a^3$, for infinitely many u(you can reduce the possibility of u, but there are more than 1 u, and some of them make this problem hard to solve

Does this answer your question? Diophantine equation $n^3+3=m^2$ - found from J. W. Tanner's comment.

Oh I checked that and another informations related to that, but what I can know was that the number of solution is finite and can be bounded by incredibly large number(or just Im too stupid so that I missed some important information)

Umm...I think I was a bit stupid. I found some books that has a possibility to solve my problem, but I don't want to buy books to solve this problem....
